# Karate Framework- is there a way to use my own application.properties file or replace individual properties with my own values during execution?

Tags: testing, properties, karate

Just wondering if anyone knows how to load a custom application.properties file in a karate framework script OR of it's possible to replace selected properties values of the default application.properties file, in order to test different value dependent scenarions?